# Pandas groupby with categorical and apply copies index to additional column

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following MWE with three alternative last lines:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(100)*3})
(df.assign(mybins = lambda df: pd.cut(df['a'],bins=np.linspace(0,300,6)))
   .groupby('mybins')
   .sum()
   #.apply(lambda x: x.sum())
   #.apply(lambda x: x.count()/float(len(df))*100)
)
```

So I have a DataFrame with floats. I want to groupby bins of column 'a' and do some calculations. When I use the `.sum` function it works as expected, it returns the bins as index and the sum of each bin as column values.

Now, when I use the apply function to calculate the sums, somehow the groupby index is also cast as an additional column 'mybins' in the dataframe, and the sum is applied to both columns. So now I have a column 'a' with the sums of `a` and a column 'mybins' with lists of the bin edges times `sum(a)`. This is not what I want/expected.

My final goal is to use `apply` to calculate percentages, but then I get an error (unsupported operand types), so I need to fix this strange behaviour. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is that what you want - pay attention at `.groupby('mybins')['a']` (**['a']**):

```
In [270]: %paste
(df.assign(mybins = lambda df: pd.cut(df['a'],bins=np.linspace(0,300,6)))
   .groupby('mybins')['a']
   #.sum()
   #.apply(lambda x: x.sum())
   .apply(lambda x: x.sum()/float(len(x))*100)
)
## -- End pasted text --
Out[270]:
mybins
(0, 60]        3150.0
(60, 120]      9150.0
(120, 180]    15150.0
(180, 240]    21150.0
(240, 300]    27000.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

BTW you can achieve the same result in a more pandas idiomatic way:

```
In [273]: %paste
(df.assign(mybins = lambda df: pd.cut(df['a'],bins=np.linspace(0,300,6)))
   .groupby('mybins')
   .mean() * 100
)
## -- End pasted text --
Out[273]:
                  a
mybins
(0, 60]      3150.0
(60, 120]    9150.0
(120, 180]  15150.0
(180, 240]  21150.0
(240, 300]  27000.0
```

**Explanation:**

given:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
   s         n s2        n2  n3
0  a  0.629772  a  6.297724   1
1  d  0.496197  d  4.961974   0
2  a  0.801868  a  8.018679   0
3  d  0.461914  d  4.619140   3
4  c  0.259175  c  2.591751   0
5  b  0.797740  b  7.977401   0
6  a  0.508496  a  5.084962   1
7  b  0.242306  b  2.423056   2
8  c  0.218082  c  2.180820   2
9  d  0.060125  d  0.601247   3
```

if we try to use `.apply()` for summing up the groups, we get:

```
In [34]: df.groupby('s').apply(lambda x: x.sum())
Out[34]:
     s         n   s2         n2  n3
s
a  aaa  1.940136  aaa  19.401364   2
b   bb  1.040046   bb  10.400456   2
c   cc  0.477257   cc   4.772571   2
d  ddd  1.018236  ddd  10.182361   6
```

because `apply()` will be applied on all columns, including the `groupby` column - `s` in this example

prove with `.apply(lambda x: print(x))` instead of `.apply(lambda x: x.sum())`

```
In [35]: df.groupby('s').apply(lambda x: print(x))
   s         n s2        n2  n3
0  a  0.629772  a  6.297724   1
2  a  0.801868  a  8.018679   0
6  a  0.508496  a  5.084962   1
   s         n s2        n2  n3
0  a  0.629772  a  6.297724   1
2  a  0.801868  a  8.018679   0
6  a  0.508496  a  5.084962   1
   s         n s2        n2  n3
5  b  0.797740  b  7.977401   0
7  b  0.242306  b  2.423056   2
   s         n s2        n2  n3
4  c  0.259175  c  2.591751   0
8  c  0.218082  c  2.180820   2
   s         n s2        n2  n3
1  d  0.496197  d  4.961974   0
3  d  0.461914  d  4.619140   3
9  d  0.060125  d  0.601247   3
Out[35]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

NOTE1: you see all columns including the `groupby` column

NOTE2: you see 5 groups instead of expected 4. [With groupby, the applied function is called one extra time to see if certain optimizations can be done.](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2656)

Now let's try to do it using `.sum()` function:

```
In [37]: df.groupby('s').sum()
Out[37]:
          n         n2  n3
s
a  1.940136  19.401364   2
b  1.040046  10.400456   2
c  0.477257   4.772571   2
d  1.018236  10.182361   6
```

`sum()` was smart enough to remove all non-numeric columns and if also removes the `groupby` column when applying `sum`:

```
In [38]: df.groupby('n3').sum()
Out[38]:
           n         n2
n3
0   2.354980  23.549805
1   1.138269  11.382686
2   0.460388   4.603876
3   0.522039   5.220387
```

we just grouped by another numeric column: `n3` and the `sum()` wasn't applied on that `groupby` column

Comment: Hi @MaxU, thanks for your reply! That's a great workaround, I didn't know about this functionality. Any chance you have an explanation for the different behaviour of `sum` and `apply`? W.r.t the second suggestion, I see I made a mistake in my MWE, it's supposed to be `x.sum()/float(len(df))`. I'll change that in the question.

Comment: @Peter9192, it'll work with `count()` as it is. I'm trying now to write a short explanation..